# Xamarin Forms Login page is not connecting to my web service

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, httpclient

Hello I am working on a Xamarin forms app that has a login screen when the user puts in the username and password and clicks the login button its supposed to validate with my web service. however it's not doing that I just get the login failed message

EDIT: Now I get a crash on iOS with the following error:

> The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to
>   a server that is pretending to be “service.brainstorminstruments.com”
>   which could put your confidential information at risk.

heres my xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="LoginNavigation.LoginPage" Title="Login">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Sign Up" Clicked="OnSignUpButtonClicked" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Username" />
            <Entry x:Name="usernameEntry" Placeholder="username" />
            <Label Text="Password" />
            <Entry x:Name="passwordEntry" IsPassword="true" />
            <Button Text="Login" Clicked="OnLoginButtonClicked" />
            <Label x:Name="messageLabel" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

EDIT I was using the wrong class

heres the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace LoginNavigation
{
    public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LoginPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        async void OnSignUpButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync (new SignUpPage ());
        }

        async void OnLoginButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

var postContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username","usernameEntry"),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password","passwordEntry")
                    });

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var serverResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://service.brainstorminstruments.com/api/login", postContent);
var serverResponseString = await serverResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

//theEditor.Text = serverResponseString;

Response theResponseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(serverResponseString);



                if (theResponseObject.status == "success") {
                App.IsUserLoggedIn = true;
                Navigation.InsertPageBefore (new MainPage (), this);
                await Navigation.PopAsync ();
            } else {
                messageLabel.Text = "Login failed";
                passwordEntry.Text = string.Empty;
                theEditor.Text += theResponseObject.status + "\n";
                theEditor.Text += theResponseObject.message + "\n";


            }
        }


    }
}
```

i'm new to http client so any help would be amazing!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you actually examined the response you get back from the server for any error codes or messages?  If you are getting a response at all then that means it was able to connect to the server.

Comment: @Jason I have not

Comment: why do you have signup and login handlers on both pages?  Are you sure it's calling the correct one?

Comment: @Jason I was using the wrong class but there is still a issue please check out the edited question thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: @Phoneswapshop There should be more to the error, can you include the full error message include the domain, code,userInfo, etc..

Answer (score 0):

> The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “service.brainstorminstruments.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.

Out of all the items list below, without the full error being produced or knowing what iOS version you are working on (assuming it is iOS10), I am going to *assume* that date/time on your device or macOS is incorrect.

This can also be caused by multiple issues:

- Is the device date/time wrong, or if running on a simulator is the date/time on your macOS correct
- Using a self-signed cert signed
- No valid root certificate for the certificate chain.

List of available trusted root certificates in iOS 10

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207177

Apple's HTTPS Server Trust Evaluation:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2232/_index.html

Note: Your service does fail the `ssllabs.com` evaluation in a number of areas for supporting insecure ciphers but that will not cause iOS to fail.

- https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=service.brainstorminstruments.com&hideResults=on

Comment: thanks for the reply what ended up being the issue is that my web blocker was blocking the service url once i tried it on another network the app no longer crashes, however i'm getting an error saying the username and password is not correct now any ideas why this is? thanks in advance!

Comment: @Phoneswapshop In your code sample, your `usernameEntry` and `passwordEntry` should be something like `passwordEntry.Text` *without* the quotes as right now you are actually sending the text `usernameEntry` & `passwordEntry` to your service.